# Is there any explicit result of $\prod_{s=1}^{n-1} \sin^s(s\pi/n)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

$\prod_{s=1}^{n-1} \sin^s(s\pi/n)$.

I came into this when calculating $\det(\omega^{ij}),\omega=\exp(2\pi i/n)$, whose origin form is like $\prod_{s=1}^{n-1} (1-\omega^s)^s$.

I just wonder if there is an explicit result of this product. Thanks for viewing.